# Removing an ancestor path from an entity

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

In Google Datastore, I have two kinds of entities: Parent and Child.

```
Parent:
  - name

Child
  - ancestor: Parent
  - name
```

I would like to programmatically remove the link between the child and the parent using the Java Client SDK. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really remove the link; i.e. you cannot update the existing entities. From the Datastore documentation at - https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#ancestor_paths

> The association between an entity and its parent is permanent, and
>   cannot be changed once the entity is created.

You will have to read each entity, create a new entity without the parent (basically copying all properties to the new entity), and delete the old entity. If the Child entities' keys are used in any other entity (e.g. a property of type Key), you may need to update those entities as well.